# Delphi: How to change cell color in StringGrid by ButtonClick

Tags: delphi, rad, tstringgrid

I decided to do a little project. It's a work with two-dimensional array, we all know it from Math class. 
I'd like to color main diagonal in StringGrid by red color in ButtonClick procedure. I know how to find main diagonal with FOR cycle but I don't know how to change the color.
Something like example, but it doesn't work.

> Stringgrid1.cells[i,j].color:=clRed;

Comment: Nope, this is not what I want. It's not on button click and I don't believe that I need such a long code to change color in one cell.

Comment: Hey sorry to break your bubble, the only way to change cell colour in standard `TStringGrid` is to use the [`OnDrawCellEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.OnDrawCell)

Comment: So that means I can't change it on ButtonClick?

Comment: Sure you can, you will have to save state somewhere. You could use the Objects[] property for that. Then you can check that state in the `OnDrawCell` event

Comment: I will try to code it, thanks.